# countTrailingZeros for Integer

Tags: haskell, biginteger

I was wondering if there was a fast way to calculate the number of trailing zeros of an Integer in Haskell. This operation makes sense for Integer but is unfortunately wrapped up with other operations that don't make sense in FiniteBits. The only way I know to do this is with a loop. Isn't there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Since `Integer` is arbitrarily large I don't think you can avoid having some sort of loop... `FiniteBits` is the right abstraction for O(1) counting of trailing zeroes.

Comment: `countTrailingZeros` in a binary or decimal sense?

Comment: Why would a loop be slower than any other method of implementing this? If speed is the goal, write the code, profile, then decide if it needs to be improved.

Comment: The sense is Binary as in FiniteBits. A loop over the bits of an integer is worse than a loop over the limbs of a integer

Comment: I don't know much about Haskell, sorry, but I do know that there are clever algorithms to count the trailing zeros of a 32 bit integer that are faster than looping and shifting repeatedly. Take a look on the Hacker's Delight website. You only need to do that for the last non-zero limb, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure there's a way to get access to the limbs otherwise I would have already done that.